# Cómo invocar un método asíncrono perteneciente a una clase del mismo tipo en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

Resulta que estoy programando el cliente de un Login que se conecta a un servicio web para validarse, utilizando asp.NET con C#. Parece ser que obtengo un error de compilación al llamar al método estático CreateLoginAsync fuera de la clase AsyncTaskLogin, a pesar de que lo intento invocar mediante una instancia de la misma.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Vaersacces
{
//Plantilla para datos del Login
public class LoginData
{
    string user;
    string pass;

    public LoginData(string user, string pass)
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

}

//Clase Asíncrona para llamar al Web Service 
public class AsyncTaskLogin
{

    private string user;
    private string pass;

    public AsyncTaskLogin(string user, string pass)
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
    }


    //Instancia de un nuevo cliente
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    //Se asignan los datos a la nueva instancia
    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("dirección de la api");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        Uri uri = await CreateLoginAsync();
    }

    //Método para postear un objeto tipo LoginData en formato Json
    static async Task<Uri> CreateLoginAsync()
    {
        LoginData login = new LoginData(user, pass);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
            "login/users", login);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return response.Headers.Location;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: que dice el mesanje de error ?

Answer (score 1):

El metodo que asigna el url de la api es `RunAsync()` deberias invocarlo en primer lugar

Si quieres invocarlo usando `static` primero va el `RunAsync()` y luego el `CreateLoginAsync()`

```
bool LoginCorrecto(string user, string pass)
{
    LoginData data = new LoginData(user, pass);

    await AsyncTaskLogin.RunAsync();

    var uri = await AsyncTaskLogin.CreateLoginAsync(data);

    return false;
}
```

Si vas a usar la instancia de la clase puede configurar esto en el constructor, la clase seria algo como esto

```
public class AsyncTaskLogin
{

    private HttpClient client = null;

    public AsyncTaskLogin()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("dirección de la api");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<Uri> CreateLoginAsync(LoginData login)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
            "login/users", login);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return response.Headers.Location;
    }

}
```

entonces si puedes usar el codigo que usaste ya que al realizar el `new` de `AsyncTaskLogin` en el constructor configuras el `HttpClient`

Comment: Disculpa, para cuando has respondido ya había modificado el código para hacerlo de una forma un poco más elegante, pero a su vez obtengo un error nuevo cuando intento instanciar el objeto LoginData en el método CreateLoginAsync(). El error dice "se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo método o propiedad no estáticos". Actualizo al nuevo código por si puedes encontrar el problema.

Comment: estas teniendo problema entre los static y las variables de instancia, cuando defines los parametros "user" y "pass" los defines de instancia, pero el resto de los metodo son static, eso no funciona. Quizas debas pasar los datos de user y pass como parametro de CreateLoginAsync(), no aplica desde el constructor